# Possible Paste From Textarea into another textarea input using button? | jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**How to make Paste Button Working?**

I have 1 element textarea for My Text.

```
<textarea id="myText">Ananda</textarea>
```

I want to Paste it into another input text .

```
<input type="text" id="resultPaste">
```

I have button for Paste from `#myText` to `#resultPaste` .

```
<span class="btn-main btn-paste">PASTE</span>
```

My code
**jQuery :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".btn-paste").click(function() {
        var text = $('#myText').val()
    $('#resultPaste').append(text);
 });
});
```

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```js
$(".btn-paste").click(function() {
  var text = $('#myText').val();
    $('#resultPaste').append(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<textarea id="myText">Ananda</textarea>
<br>
<button class="btn-primary btn-paste">PASTE</button>
<br><br>
<input type="text" id="resultPaste">
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/4fukuma/j1e0aLnv/1)

Comment: Do you want to add the contents of the textarea to the input field, or overwrite existing data in the input with the text from your textarea?

Comment: Do you really want "Anada" to be added to what could already be in `#resultPaste`?  Like in order to keep the previous value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn-primary").click(function() {
    var text = $('#myText').val();

  $('#resultPaste').val( $('#resultPaste').val()+text);
  });
});
```

append dont work on textarea

Comment: append is tags for end append

Comment: That is a solution where the text is added to any previous value... +1

Comment: correct answer to be choosen for this question , agree with @LouysPatriceBessette +1

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what append does, but in order to set the value, you must use

```
el.val('something')
```

```js
$(".btn-paste").click(function() {
  var text = $('#myText').val();
  $('#resultPaste').val(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<textarea id="myText">Ananda</textarea>
<br>
<button class="btn-primary btn-paste">PASTE</button>
<br><br>
<input type="text" id="resultPaste">
```

Comment: "I don't know what append does" RTFM ;)

Comment: Explanations could be a little improved... I don't know why so much upvotes on that.

Comment: The value in the input element is [object Object] . why? :(( but, it's work in the fiddle.

Comment: @Ananda: you probaly defined `text` as `$('#myText')` and forgot the `.val()` part.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are just copying all of the text over just use `.val()` on both the copy `<textarea>` and the past `<textarea>`.

```js
$(".btn-paste").click(function() {
    $('#resultPaste').val($('#myText').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<textarea id="myText">Ananda</textarea>
<br>
<button class="btn-primary btn-paste">PASTE</button>
<br><br>
<input type="text" id="resultPaste">
```

Answer (score -1):

No jquery

- Wait DOM loaded
- Get the button for change the text
- Get the input to put the text
- Get the text and put that.

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
 document.getElementsByClassName("btn-paste")[0].addEventListener("click", () => {
 document.getElementById("resultPaste").value = document.getElementById("myText").value;
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<textarea id="myText">Ananda</textarea>
<br>
<button class="btn-primary btn-paste">PASTE</button>
<br><br>
<input type="text" id="resultPaste"/>
```

Comment: the OP is already using jQuery, and even tagged the question as jQuery.

Comment: he has also put the javascript tag, so this is completely valid